# Intergrating PHP for output email with 'Protoform'

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

I have this form set up on my website: http://cssrevolt.com/upload/files/protoform/

It's all customized and working just as the stand alone demo above.

**The protoform came with a `send.php` file that consists of the PHP below:**

```
<?php
    echo "<div id=\"response\">";


  $name            = $_POST['name'];
  $email           = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone       = $_POST['telephone'];
  $preference      = $_POST['preference'];
  $message         = $_POST['message'];

  if ( ($name=='') && ($email=='') && ($telephone=='') && ($message=='')) { 

        echo "<p>Please fill all the required fields<span>*</span></em></p>";

  }
  else {

        echo "<p>Submitting ok, server response:</p>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>Name: ".$name."</li>";
        echo "<li>E-mail: ".$email."</li>";
        echo "<li>Telephone: ".$telephone."</li>";
        echo "<li>Preference: ".$preference."</li>";
        echo "<li>Message:".$message."</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
  }  


  echo "</div>";
?>
```

**I'm still considerably novice with PHP, but from what it looks like I should just have to insert some code that will spit the data at a defined email address, right?**

*!UPDATED:* Code attempt below and still can't get form data to send to my email. (Have replaced youremail with actual)

```
<?php
    echo "<div id=\"response\">";


  $name            = $_POST['name'];
  $email           = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone       = $_POST['telephone'];
  $preference      = $_POST['preference'];
  $message         = $_POST['message'];

  if ( ($name=='') && ($email=='') && ($telephone=='') && ($message=='')) { 

        echo "<p>Please fill all the required fields<span>*</span></em></p>";

  }
  else {

        echo "<p>Submitting ok, server response:</p>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>Name: ".$name."</li>";
        echo "<li>E-mail: ".$email."</li>";
        echo "<li>Telephone: ".$telephone."</li>";
        echo "<li>Preference: ".$preference."</li>";
        echo "<li>Message:".$message."</li>";
        echo "</ul>";


        // Body of message
        $message = "Submitting ok, server response: \n
        Name: $name \n
        E-mail: $email \n
        Telephone:  $telephone \n
        Preference: $preference \n
        Message: $message \n";
        //Recipient
        $to = "your@email.dom";
        //Subject of email
        $subject = "Message from $name";
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
        mail($to, $subject, $message);

  }  


  echo "</div>";
?>
```

*Derivation of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253461/using-protoform-where-is-data-via-ajax-at*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo "<div id=\"response\">";


  $name            = $_POST['name'];
  $email           = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone       = $_POST['telephone'];
  $preference      = $_POST['preference'];
  $message         = $_POST['message'];

  if ( ($name=='') && ($email=='') && ($telephone=='') && ($message=='')) { 

        echo "<p>Please fill all the required fields<span>*</span></em></p>";

  }
  else {

        echo "<p>Submitting ok, server response:</p>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>Name: ".$name."</li>";
        echo "<li>E-mail: ".$email."</li>";
        echo "<li>Telephone: ".$telephone."</li>";
        echo "<li>Preference: ".$preference."</li>";
        echo "<li>Message:".$message."</li>";
        echo "</ul>";


        // Body of message
        $message = "Submitting ok, server response: \n
        Name: $name \n
        E-mail: $email \n
        Telephone:  $telephone \n
        Preference: $preference \n
        Message: $message \n";
        //Recipient
        $to = "your@email.dom";
        //Subject of email
        $subject = "Message from $name";
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
        mail($to, $subject, $message);

  }  


  echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Plugging this in should allow the submit to email action now?!

Comment: ...still didn't send to email.

Comment: Bleh - needed the sender, thanks man.